# How to translate to a HTML code ("&something;")

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to translate a symbol to its HTML code, e.g. `'` to `&rsquo;` with this code:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="test">&rsquo;</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select='translate(title, $apos, $test)' />
```

This works:

```
<xsl:variable name="test">&#39;</xsl:variable>
```

But is it possible to make the first example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="test">&amp;rsquo;</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="input">'sfdds'</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$apos"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$test"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$result" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="input"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($input, $value)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, $value)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$replacement"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, $value)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
&rsquo;sfdds&rsquo;
```

Comment: When I tried something like this, my html at the client side literally said `&rsquo;`

Answer (score 3):

`&rsquo;` is a HTML entity, whereas XSLT is written using XML which only has 5 entities defined. See the Wikipedia page on [XML / HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

You could potentially use DOCTYPE to add the HTNML entities so that the XML parser that parses your XSLT can understand things like `&rsquo;`, see the following examples:

http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xml_creating_entities.cfm